# in a program to find permutations of string with 3 characters, a variable in program logs differently than the value expected?

Tags: javascript

in a program to find permutations of string with 3 characters, a variable in program logs differently than the value expected? variable px logs differently but when pushed into an array,it always outputs as ["b","a","c"]?

program to find permutation of a string with 3 characters

```js
function perm(str) {
  var str = str.split('');
  var res = []
  var bag = []

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    n = 1;
    var px = str;



    for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
      if (j == 1) {}
      if (j == 2) {
        var tempx = px[1];
        var tempy = px[2];

        px[1] = tempy;
        px[2] = tempx;
      }
      console.log(px)
      bag.push(px)
    }

    if (i < (str.length - 1)) {
      tempa = str[0];
      tempb = str[0 + 1];

      str[0 + 1] = tempa;
      str[0] = tempb;
    }
  }

  console.log(bag);
}

perm("abc");
```

Comment: What is a permutation? I bet this code can be improved.

Comment: permutation is finding each of several possible ways in which a set or number of things can be ordered or arranged,suppose you have string "abc",you need to output all the ways characters "a" "b" "c" can be arranged to create new string

Comment: It will be helpfull if you put a snippet to run the code

Answer (score 0):

The js have primitive types (as number, string, boolean) and object. The object type save by reference, when primitive save by value. For example,

```js
var obj = {
  a: "Hello",
  b: 2
};

console.log(obj); // {a: "Hello", b: 2};

var ref = obj;
console.log(obj) // {a: "Hello", b: 2};

obj.a = "new string";
ref.b = -1;

// The output will be the same, because objects save by reference.
console.log(obj); // {a: "new string", b: -1}
console.log(ref); // {a: "new string", b: -1}
```

You created the same error with `px` array (array is also save by ref). For fix this, you should create `px` array every time in this loop `for (j = 1; j < 3; j++)`
Fixed snippet.

```js
function perm(str){
    //var str=str.split('');

    var res=[]

    var bag=[]



    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        n=1;
        for(j=1;j<3;j++){
            var px=str.split('');
            if(j==1){

            }
            if(j==2){
                var tempx=px[1];
                var tempy=px[2];

                px[1]=tempy;
                px[2]=tempx;


            }

            console.log(px)

            bag.push(px)
        }


        if(i<(str.length-1)){

            tempa=str[0];
            tempb=str[0+1];

            str[0+1]=tempa;
            str[0]=tempb;

        }
    }
    console.log(bag);
}

perm("abc");
```